# How to ignore particular test case in MSTest

Tags: c#, unit-testing, testing, mstest

I am trying to ignore test case by adding `Ignore` keyword for `DataRow` attribute:

```
[TestClass]
public class MathTests
{
    [TestMethod]
    [DataRow(1, 1, 2)]
    [DataRow(2, 2, 3), Ignore]
    public void Sum_Test(int a, int b, int expectedSum)
    {
        var sut = new Math();
        
        var sum = sut.Sum(a, b);
        
        Assert.IsTrue(sum == expectedSum);
    }
}

public class Math
{
    public int Sum(int a, int b)
    {
        return a + b;
    }
}
```

but it ignores the *whole* test:

[image]

- Target: .NET 6
- MSTest.TestFramework: v2.2.8
- IDE: Rider

---

How particular test *case* can be ignored in MSTest?

Comment: Try to add an other empty TestMethod to MathTests class. What do you see not in test list?

Comment: I added other TestMethod and I can see it in the test list, and its running ok.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, there is no `Ignore` keyword. What are you doing is just combining 2 attributes in the same line. So, your code is equivalent to:

```
[TestClass]
public class MathTests
{
    [TestMethod]
    [DataRow(1, 1, 2)]
    [DataRow(2, 2, 3)]
    [Ignore]
    public void Sum_Test(int a, int b, int expectedSum)
    {
        var sut = new Math();
        
        var sum = sut.Sum(a, b);
        
        Assert.IsTrue(sum == expectedSum);
    }
}
```

[21.3 Attribute specification](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/attributes#213-attribute-specification)

> Attributes are specified in attribute sections. An attribute section
> consists of a pair of square brackets, which surround a
> comma-separated list of one or more attributes. The order in which
> attributes are specified in such a list, and the order in which
> sections attached to the same program entity are arranged, is not
> significant. For instance, the attribute specifications [A][B],
> [B][A], [A, B], and [B, A] are equivalent.

What you could do:

1. The easiest solution is just to comment particular data rows out. (or you can use precompile variables. In this case, it will be easier to enable all ignored test cases)

   PRO: This is very easy.

   CONTRA: You won't be able to see these test cases in GUI
2. You can create 2 tests and mark one of these tests with `TestCathegory` attribute.

   PRO: It will be possible to see this test in GUI.

   PRO: You'll be able to execute tests with or exclude specific `TestCathegory`.

   CONTRA: You'll have to duplicate your test.

   CONTRA: You'll have to use command line parameters to include or exclude specific `TestCathegory` on your build server.